# Icecast2 not logging in access.log

Tags: logging, ubuntu-14.04, vps, icecast, awstats

I'm using icecast2 on a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS machine.
It is not logging anything in the access.log file.
It is complete empty.

I need it fixed for using AWStats.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Icecast through package management (apt), then it should automatically start and log to `/var/log/icecast2/`.

If it doesn't do that, then you'll need to explain what your setup looks like.